# Bertrand's Postulate Extension: Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I seem to have come up with a stronger version of Bertrand's Postulate.

For any $n\geq 4$, there exists a pair of Twin Primes between $n$ and $2n$.

I have computationally verified it uptil $n=50000$ .

Does this trivially seem to hold true? I am an undergraduate student in mathematics learning number theory so I thought of discussing my idea here.

Comment: Are you content with a large search limit for this conjecture ? A proof is hopeless which has been pointed out.

Comment: I will try to verify this for a larger value of n. I thought of discussing this mathematically (but a proof is hopeless as pointed out) before proceeding computationally.

Answer (score 2):

This is strictly stronger than the twin prime conjecture which is open, so this is also open. It would follow asymptotically from a strong version of the twin prime conjecture which gives the asymptotic density of twin primes, namely the [first Hardy-Littlewood conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#First_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture).

This would be the analogue of the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) for twin primes; the prime number theorem itself also proves a stronger asymptotic version of Bertrand's postulate, namely that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that for $n \ge N$ there exists a prime between $n$ and $(1 + \varepsilon) n$ (and the first Hardy-Littlewood conjecture would imply the same for twin primes, I think, at least with a sufficiently good error term). For more on these sorts of statements you can see, for example, the Wikipedia page on [Legendre's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture).

Comment: However, is my observation something new in your opinion? Most postulates/ theorems that I have come across talk about the existence of a prime and not twin primes as such

Comment: I haven't seen the precise statement before but again, asymptotically this (and stronger statements) follows from the first Hardy-Littlewood conjecture.